# java 8 : compile Error: cannot access Synchronization

Tags: java, hibernate, java-8, jta

I have a legacy code written for Java 6 and I want to compile it with a `Jdk` 8

This code use `seam` and `hibernate`, I didn't change the dependencies versions. In fact, I've really just changed the jdk.

I have a compile error on the `getSession` method from Hibernate:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public abstract class AbstractComponent  implements java.io.Serializable
{
    @In(value="grogDatabase", create = true, required = true)
    private Session _grogDatabase;

    /**
     * @return the hibernate database {@link Session} injected via Seam into this component.
     * Warning : DO NOT use injected data in component constructors !
     */
    protected Session getSession()
    {
        return _grogDatabase;
    }
}
```

and

```
@SuppressWarnings({"serial", "SeamAnnotationsInconsistencyInspection"})
public abstract class AbstractConversationComponent extends AbstractComponent
{
    @In(value="myDatabase", scope = CONVERSATION)
    private org.jboss.seam.persistence.ManagedHibernateSession _myDatabase;

    /**
     * @return the hibernate database {@link Session} injected via Seam into this component.
     * Warning : DO NOT use injected data in component constructors !
     */
    @Override
    protected Session getSession()
    {
        try
        {
            Session hSession = _myDatabase.getSession();
            return hSession;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
 }
```

The error message I get is

```
 /.../AbstractConversationComponent.java:32: error: cannot access Synchronization
    [javac]             Session hSession = _myDatabase.getSession();
    [javac]                                             ^
    [javac]   class file for javax.transaction.Synchronization not found
```

I get this is a missing dependency, says javax.transaction.jta, but why a change in `Jdk` would imply a change in my dependencies ?

Including a dependency without being able to check its compatibility seems dangerous to me..

**Edit:** Here are some traces of the same compilation with various Jdk:

1.6:

```
$ JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64 ant clean deploy.local.archive
...
[javac] 5 warnings
```

1.7:

```
$ JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/j2sdk1.7-oracle/ ant clean deploy.local.archive
...
[javac] 5 warnings
```

1.8:

```
$ JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-x64/ ant clean deploy.local.archive
...
[javac] 1 error
[javac] 5 warnings
```

**Edit:**  I checked and jta.jar was indeed part of the running classpath, but not of the compile classpath.

So I added it manually to the list with the others in build.xml, and now it works with jdk 8. But this still doesn't make sense to me, and I'd really like to understand why this is happening :)

```
<path id="class.path">
    <pathelement location="${env.JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar"/><!-- Only for ExcludeTaglet -->
    <pathelement location="${project.ext.dir}/dev/servlet.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${project.ext.dir}/run/log4j.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${project.ext.dir}/run/dom4j.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${project.ext.dir}/run/castor.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${project.ext.dir}/run/commons-httpclient.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${project.ext.dir}/run/commons-io.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${project.ext.dir}/run/commons-lang.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${project.ext.dir}/run/commons-validator.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${project.ext.dir}/run/commons-vfs.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${project.ext.dir}/run/commons-net.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${project.ext.dir}/run/hibernate.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${project.ext.dir}/run/hibernate-validator.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${project.ext.dir}/run/jboss-seam.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${project.ext.dir}/run/persistence-api.jar"/>
    <!-- added for jdk 1.8 --> 
    <pathelement location="${project.ext.dir}/run/jta.jar"/>

    <pathelement location="${project.ext.dir}/run/jsf-api.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${project.ext.dir}/run/jcaptcha-all.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${project.ext.dir}/run/richfaces-ui-3.3.1.CR3.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${project.ext.dir}/run/richfaces-impl-3.3.1.CR3.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${project.ext.dir}/run/yarfraw.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${project.ext.dir}/wrapper/${platform}/lib/wrapper.jar"/>
</path>
```

Comment: I am pretty sure JTA was not part of JDK 1.6. Are you sure you did not add it on your own, say as `endorsed`?

Comment: I'm sure JTA was not in jdk too :) I've re-checked it works well with the other jdk (see edits)
The only thing I see would be if some syntax to include dependency have changed and so that with jdk 1.8 it is not able to see something that is here.